# Removing bullet point characters from text file with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a large text file in which some lines start with a bullet point (•).  I'd like to remove those.  I've tried

```
sed 's/\u2022//g' filename.txt
```

but that doesn't match the bullets.  I've also tried pasting the bullet into my sed command, but also with no success.

E: The output of

```
sed --version
```

is

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

E2:  If it helps figure out how to capture the bullet characters, they were originally added in Access.

E3:  As suggesting in the comments,

```
echo -n '•' | hexdump -C
```

returns

```
00000000  95                                                |.|
00000001
```

Comment: could you try with something like this: sed "s/$(echo -ne '\u2022')//g" file1, from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196780/is-there-an-alternative-to-sed-that-supports-unicode

Comment: Can you simply copy & paste the bullet as is on sed? That worked for me on the past.

Comment: `echo "abc•xyz" | sed 's/•//g'`?

Comment: @MatiasBarrios I've tried copying and pasting the bullets directly from the file, and it doesn't capture them that way either.

Comment: Add output of `echo -n "•" | hexdump -C` to your question.

Comment: 95? Try `sed 's/\x95//g' file`

Comment: @Cyrus `sed 's/\x95//g'` solved my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: This might be an OS issue. On Mac option+8 inserts a Unicode bullet. Windows apparently uses ASCII 0x95. It also depends on the encoding of your text file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\x95//g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a working command for me:

```
# Force paste the bullet into the command line
sed 's/^•//g' filename.txt
```

If it doesn't work, try escaping with `echo`:

```
sed 's/^'"$(echo -ne '\u2022')"'//g' filename.txt
```

As [PesaThe suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116546/removing-bullet-point-characters-from-text-file-with-sed/48116702?noredirect=1#comment83209570_48116702), you can also use `printf` for escaping:

```
sed 's/^'"$(printf '\u2022')"'//g' filename.txt
```

Comment: `printf '\u2022'` might be preferred.

Comment: @PesaThe I've been using `echo -ne` all the time.

Comment: It's a portability issue - `echo -ne` will do different things on different boxes while `printf` will behave the same everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `sed` doesn't understand `\u` sequences.
According to user manual it should be compatible with POSIX.2 BRE, which i think should work, but it doesn't.

You can try capturing the hexadecimal sequence (which i got using `hexdump -C`).

```
sed  's/^\xe2\x80\xa2//g' filename.txt
```

Or, alternatively, you could force `bash` to parse it. Just add a `$` before the string.

```
sed $'s/\u2022//g' filename.txt
```